# Java - for Loop an Array with a Conditional Check problem

Tags: arrays, for-loop, if-statement

This is part of a practice activity I am working on while studying Java, so everything but what is shown here is hidden and I cant alter anything but what is between comment marks on this code. As the code between comments started blank, everything shown there is my own code.

I cant figure out what I am doing wrong here.

The idea is that if the weight of an item is under 20oz and the customer has a loyalty card, the system should "discount" 5% of the items weight.

```
12    float calculateWeight(float[] weights, boolean hasLoyaltyCard) {
13        float totalWeight = 0;
14 //
15            for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) { // (for) loop the array
16                float weight = weights[i];             // float var with looped array returns
17                if (weight < 20f && hasLoyaltyCard) {  // check for under 20oz AND boolean
18                    weight *= 0.95f;                   // if true, multiply weight by 5% & update
19                } 
20                totalWeight = weight;                  // update totalWeight with weight calculation
21            }    
22 //
23        return totalWeight;
24       }
```

Can someone please give me some insight as to why this is failing (not just the fix, but also the reason)?

Thank you for any help.

Since the error statements mention line 16 "float weight = weights[i];", I keep thinking the issue is in my call to declare and initialize the variable "weight" with the value returned from the "weights" array loop, but I cant find anything to the contrary in any of the material leading up to this activity.

So to this point, most of my attempts have just been changing operators in the loop or trying different syntax (as well as attempting to stare the code into submission, which only resulted in a headache and frustration).

I am getting errors stating that out of the 4 checks run, 2 fail, 2 pass.

Float [1] and [2] checks are failing and returning "expected 60, but was 21.0" and "expected 59.05, but was 21.0", respectively.
Float [3] and [4] checks are passing for both true and false conditions.

By the results I am getting, I would have to guess the array holds (19f, 20f, 21f) or (19.0, 20.0, 21.0).

```
CheckoutMachineTest > calculateWeightTest(float[], boolean, float) > com.ata.CheckoutMachineTest.calc
ulateWeightTest(float[], boolean, float)[1] FAILED                                                   
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <60.0> but was: <21.0>                            
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)                         
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)                 
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:102)                    
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:97)                     
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:714)                        
        at com.ata.CheckoutMachineTest.calculateWeightTest(CheckoutMachineTest.java:16)              
                                                                                                     
CheckoutMachineTest > calculateWeightTest(float[], boolean, float) > com.ata.CheckoutMachineTest.calc
ulateWeightTest(float[], boolean, float)[2] FAILED                                                   
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <59.05> but was: <21.0>                           
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)                         
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)                 
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:102)                    
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:97)                     
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:714)                        
        at com.ata.CheckoutMachineTest.calculateWeightTest(CheckoutMachineTest.java:16)
```

Comment: `totalWeight` is just the weight of the last item in the array. I assume that isn't what you meant...

Answer (score 0):

at line 20

```
totalWeight += weight;
```